# change the background color of panels in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

In my project, I am trying to change the background color of all the panels inside a container. The code which I am trying is as follows:

```
container --> panel (don't change) --> panel (Change)
```

---

```
//Generated dynamically using for loop.
listeners: {
   'render': function(panel) {
        panel.body.on('click', function() {
                //here change the background color of all the panels inside the container>panel. 
        });
    }
}
```

What should I write to change the background color of the only panels which are present inside the parent panels of a main container?

I tried:

```
Ext.each('panel',function(){this.body.setStyle('background','white')}),
```

But the above approach is giving me the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setStyle' of undefined

**EDIT**:

Here, I am looking for a method of extjs which quite do the same work as jQuery's `children()`.

```
$('#containerID').children('panel').children('panel').css(change background color);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirements you will always have a sum of 9 components you are looking at -1 the you start from. The shortest way is to use the `each()` method of the MixedCollection (at runtime all items are within a MixedCollection)

```
'render': function(panel) {
    panel.body.on('click', function() {
         panel.items.each(function(p){ p.body.setStyle('background','white'); }, this)
    },this);
}
```

This may not be the variant with the best performance but knowing your requirement from the last question I can say that this is the easiest. And in addition it will be easy to maintain. And read the article about delegates that I posted in the comments of the last question!

*I hope there is now typo, cause it is untested*

**Update**

Well, you are looking for the `ownerCt` property here (at least that is the easiest way). But there are some mightier navigation methods `up()` / `down()` both can be feeded with a `ComponentQuery` string. Leave the `up()` arguments empty will return the immediate owner/activater (basically the same as `ownerCt`).

Following a working example:

```
var childItems = [], items = [];
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    childItems.push({
        xtype: 'container',
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        html: i + '',
        style: {borderColor:'#000000', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px'},
        listeners: {
            'afterrender': function(panel) {
                panel.el.on('click', function(e,t) {
                    panel.el.on('click', function(e,t) {
                    panel.el.setStyle('background','red');
                    panel.ownerCt.items.each(function(p){ if(panel.el.id != p.id) p.el.setStyle('background','white'); })
                });
             }
        }
    });
}
for (i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    items.push({
        xtype: 'container',
        layout: {
            type: 'table',
            columns: 3
        },
        style: {borderColor:'#000000', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px'},
        items: childItems
    });
}
Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
    layout: {
        type: 'table',
        // The total column count must be specified here
        columns: 3
    },
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),    
    style: {borderColor:'#000000', borderStyle:'solid', borderWidth:'1px', margin: '30px'},
    items: items
});
```

**Update 2**

To reset all try this (untested)

```
'afterrender': function(panel) {
          panel.el.on('click', function(e,t) {
              panel.el.setStyle('background','red');
              panel.ownerCt.ownerCt.items.each(function(op){ 
                   op.items.each(function(p){ 
                       if(panel.el.id != p.id) 
                          p.el.setStyle('background','white'); 
                   })
              }, this)
          });
 }
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X6kQK/4/)**

Comment: I have gone through the link you provided in the previous post. But as I am new to even DOM, I can't understand it. here what I am trying to do is that whenever the user clicks on a panel, the clicked panel will become red and other panels will become white.

Comment: Here I am clicking the child panels which are present in the parent panel. So, this is not working. I am in need of a method like `parent()` of jQuery here (I think).

Comment: Something similar to this of jQuery.. `$('#containerID').children('panel').children('panel').css(change background color);`

Comment: Hi, the previously clicked panel background color is remaining(I mean not changing to white, default), If I click in other parent panel(working fine in the same panel).  I think you need to take the owner twice and uncheck the first panel to go into the child panels.

Comment: @Mr_Green What do mean with previous? In the first comment you wrote `..the clicked panel will become red and other panels will become white..`.

Comment: yes its working good only in the same parent panel in which the child panel has been selected. not in whole container. If I select other child panel from other parent panel then the previous selected child panels background color is not changing to white. `container --> parent panels --> child panels`.

Comment: @Mr_Green Yes, But I thought this as intended... Give me a minute to update

Comment: Its working.. But happening after I click the child panel twice to change the color.. Is it happening at your side too?

Comment: Thanks for your full support.. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green The underlying DOM element wrapper (Ext.Element) for this component.

Comment: In the above code you haven't declared any var as `el`.. is it default? or you did some indirect declaration here? (right now I am going through `Ext.element` docs..)

Comment: @Mr_Green each component has a el property that is available after the component is rendered.

Comment: ohh k sorry for disturbing you and again thanks for explaining clearly :)